# Expose TimeObject fractions of a second and user-defined formatting

Tags: date-and-time, dataset

The default `TimeObject` formats ([doc page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeObject.html)), don't display fractions of seconds:

```
data = {<|"Elapsed Time" -> TimeObject[{0, 0, 2.23}] |>, <|
   "Elapsed Time" -> TimeObject[{0, 0, 2.37}] |>}
```

[image]

```
data // Dataset
```

[image]

As `TimeObject` has no format options (unlike, eg `Framed` or `Panel`) how can output format be user-defined, for example here to:

- Expose sub-second time
- Harmonize `Association` and `Dataset` formats
- Replace the clock icon with more informative metadata (eg time zone or clock id).